# Inconsequent shading problem. Tipps for a Beginner

Tags: texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I am new and try now to UV Map my model but in this process i see some problems on my model. Maybe u see whats the problem or have some advice for the next model to avoid this problems.

[image]

U see here that it looks like that my eye box isnt well connected with the rest but it is i delete some faces to connect it again manually. 
Same Lines showing on the legs.

[image]

As u see on the following pictures the result after i shade it smooth. 
I already tried as say above to delete some vertices and faces and stich them together again but it dont helped.

[image]

[image]

Hopefully u have any advice for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter edit mode. Press "3" to filter to FACES. Press "A" to select all faces, click SHIFT+N (recalculate normals) and this will make all your faces coplanar to the average facing normals.
Second thing to check: Are all of your polygonal faces connected? Because they look like they don´t. Join each vertex by selecting 2 or more vertex and press ALT+M, select "center" and this will join the vertices for your poly face.